# Logistic Growth in MATLAB -- Need help with the plot

Tags: differential, matlab

I'm working on a school project about coding the logistic growth using matlab gui,

till now everything is great, the calculation is perfect, but I'm stuck with the graph,

it always show only one point not a curve of the function,
I've tried my code in live script and the graph is perfect, the problem only shows in matlab gui,

this is part of my code

```
        LGrowth = k./(1+A*exp(-r.*t));  

        plot(t, LGrowth, 'o')
```

Note: k, r and t will be taken from the user, while A will be calculated.

can you please help me with this?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: This seems more like a programming question better suited to https://stackoverflow.com.  Also, you'll need to provide more of you Matlab program for anyone to provide meaningful assistance.

Comment: the question is about graphing the Logistic growth, the graph shows the answer only not the curve of the formula, I tried the same in live script and it worked just fine, but I face a problem when I use the GUI

Comment: never mind, I think I solved